# Change content/image when hovering an image with multiple parts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to see if possible at all, to have the image attached change an image on the side when hovering over 1,2,3...

This means there are several parts changing the side image to another image each time. My biggest question is, is it possible to do this without cutting the image into multiple parts and keeping it as a single image with multiple hover points?

[image: Hover image]

Comment: Where's your attempt at this? We help with code, we don't write it for you.

Comment: There's a lot of ways that this can be interpreted.  Can you please write some code (even if it is really bad and wrong), in order to have a starting point to work with.

Comment: You could make a table with two columns. Then if one cell is hovered, style another cell with a background image. CSS should be easy for this.

Comment: What you are referring to is an image map. [this link](https://html.com/images/how-to-make-an-image-map/) explains how it works. In my opinion your example doesn't call for it, there are much simpler and efficient ways.

Comment: A lot of hate here for asking a question... I was asking what the best approach would be, not for the code.

From the answers, It seems this is possible with either an areamap, or tables. 

Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Very old style but you can create a so called areamap. [Sample Page in German](https://www.mediaevent.de/xhtml/area-map.html) Use google chrome to translate the explanation.

But in your case its cheaper to create tabel and hover the cells ;) CSS background-image is your friend.